# How to tell git to use local files in relation to remote refs for tracking my dotfiles

Tags: git, dot-files

I’m using git to maintain my Linux “dotfiles”, which contain files from my /home, my /etc, and some entries I manually created in /boot (for systemd-boot). I’m also tracking these using a bare git repository, saved in $HOME/.cache/dotfiles, which tracks my files that i manually `git add` to it.

If necessary, you can view this repository over at this link: https://github.com/Frontear/dotfiles/tree/rewrite

I’m currently running into an issue after i accidentally deleted the repo files off my pc (I deleted $HOME/.cache/dotfiles). I remade it via `git init —bare ~/.cache/dotfiles`, and then ran into a problem. After attaching my repo remote via `git remote add`, I can’t pull because it would demand an overwrite of the local files, which I do NOT want. I want git to use the current files, match the HEAD of the remote by copying it to local, if there are any changes (somehow) just show them as unstaged etc etc, basically undo my deleting of the repo :p

How could I go about doing this? I tried to use `git fetch` followed by `git symbolic-ref HEAD refs/remotes/origin/rewrite` (I followed this advice from another stackexchange question), but im running into the issue that this leaves my local tree without a branch, since im sitting on the HEAD of the remote refs. Id want to ideally meld them into a local branch but I’ve 0 clue how to approach it. Have read through various questions I was told to reset —hard (obviously not because itll wipe + permission problems because git wont know the modifiers for some files), clean -d -f (pretty sure this also erases files).

Is what I want possible, or would I need to do some `cp` fuckery to copy the remote HEAD to a custom local branch HEAD location? Id hope not, hoping theres a native git solution for this dilemma I’m in.